# Get all class parameters & their names?

Tags: java, class, methods, parameters

I'm looking for users to be able to input a parameter name, e. "sand", and I would then like to know which Block references that name.

Reference code:

```
public class Blocks implements ContentList {
public static Block air;
public static Block spawn;
public static Block deepwater;
public static Block water;
public static Block taintedWater;
public static Block tar;
public static Block stone;
public static Block craters;
public static Block charr;
public static Block sand;
public static Block darksand;
public static Block ice;
public static Block snow;
public static Block darksandTaintedWater;
public static Block holostone;
public static Block rocks;
}
```

My attempt:

```
String targetBlock = ctx.args[2].toLowerCase();
                Block desiredBlock = Blocks.copperWall;
                for(Block block : Blocks.all()){
                    if (block.name == targetBlock){
                        desiredBlock = block;
                    }
                }
```

Obviously doesn't work, because Blocks.java does not have a .all() method
Also, the Blocks.java is auto-generated and I can not modify it or add methods, any ideas?

Comment: Reflection? If it’s generated and cannot be modified I think that’s probably your only option.

Comment: Why don't you do it as enum?

Comment: Have you tried organizing this data in a `HashMap<String, Block>`, or something similar, instead?

Comment: Hey, as I mentioned the Blocks.java class is auto-generated and I can't modify it.

Comment: Use a `HashMap<String, Block>`.  This is exactly what they're for.

Comment: It's not really that convinient for me as the parameters in Blocks.java update and change very often, AND they contain over 100+ parameters (what I mentioned above is merely a snippet), I don't really wanna re assign 100s of them every few days.

Comment: Well, the `getFields` method of the `Class` class will do it for you.  It just seems to me like the wrong design.

Comment: You can use reflection to get a list of the fields and then build the map from that. Then when you want to query it, look them up in the map. You could do this at start-up time or lazily the first time you query for a block.

Comment: Do you instantiate the `Blocks` class with corresponding `Block` fields?

Comment: Got it to work by using reflection, thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use reflection to access the field of the auto-generated Blocks file:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class Block {

    private String name;
    public Block(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
class Blocks {

    public static Block wall = new Block("wall");
    public static Block corner = new Block("corner");
     ......
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field field = Blocks.class.getDeclaredField("wall"); // get the value from the args in real program
        Block b = (Block)field.get(null);
        System.out.println(b.getName());
    }
}
```

A couple of caveats:

1. `getDeclaredField` can throw NoSuchFieldException if you will supply the name of the datafield that actually doesn't exist
2. I've assumed that the generated `Block` instances are static as it appears in the question, that's why I use `field.get(null)` and not `field.get(<something of type Blocks>)`

Comment: @aze Note that in general, reflection is a terrible idea.  You really need to get ahold of the autogenerator for this and propose a more long term solution.